# Does the minimal polynomial of a matrix have to contain all eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the minimal polynomial of a matrix have to contain all eigenvalues?
If I have the characteristic polynomial $t^2*(t-2)^2$ of a matrix, does the minimal polynomial have to contain $t$ and $t-2$ or could a minimal polynomial just be $t-2$?

I think all options for minimal polynomial are $t*(t-2)$ or $t*(t-2)^2$ or $t^2*(t-2)$ or $t^2*(t-2)^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f$ be any polynomial. Then $Av=\lambda v$ implies $A^kv=\lambda^kv$ and ultimately  $f(A)v=f(\lambda)v$. Hence if additionally $f(A)=0$ and $v\ne 0$, then certainly $f(\lambda)=0$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit? So the minimal polynomial of a matrix has to contain both eigenvalues?

Comment: @macco Yes, every eigenvalue must be a root of the minimal polynomial. If $v$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $f$ the minimal polynomial, the conditions of my last sentence are fulfilled and $f(\lambda)=0$ follows.